# How can i change cursor for a window in C#?

Tags: c#, window, cursor

When i'm trying to change cursor to a custom one, for a single window, with SetCursor() function (using user32.dll), it changes it, but when mouse starts moving, cursor changes to default one. So, there's a question appeared, how can i change cursor for a single window, with a custom cursor?

Comment: That would depend on how the window was created. WinForms/WPF/Console?

Comment: Try changing cursor from the `form` properties, that will use the custom cursor for that particular form.

Comment: Are you trying to affect the window in a different program?

Answer (score 3):

I like to wrap this in a `try` / `finally`:

```
try
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
}
finally
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

This ensures that you actually revert the cursor back - even if an error happens. What I've also done in the past (for complicated modal dialog situations) is have a stack of cursors and push the current cursor on to the stack before changing the cursor, popping it off again in the `finally` clause.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use native Windows functions.

Take a look at the [`Cursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class, and the exposed [`Cursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.cursor.aspx) property of controls, which you can set.

```
control.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it using the cursor class programtically, like this,

```
     this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

To change it back to normal,

```
     this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: I need this for using with Unity3d window...so it can't include any windows forms references.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
        this.Text = "Cursor Example";

        // The following generates a cursor from an embedded resource. 

        // To add a custom cursor, create a bitmap 
        //        1. Add a new cursor file to your project:  
        //                Project->Add New Item->General->Cursor File 

        // --- To make the custom cursor an embedded resource  --- 

        // In Visual Studio: 
        //        1. Select the cursor file in the Solution Explorer 
        //        2. Choose View->Properties. 
        //        3. In the properties window switch "Build Action" to "Embedded Resources" 

        // On the command line: 
        //        Add the following flag: 
        //            /res:CursorFileName.cur,Namespace.CursorFileName.cur 
        //         
        //        Where "Namespace" is the namespace in which you want to use the cursor
        //        and   "CursorFileName.cur" is the cursor filename.

        // The following line uses the namespace from the passed-in type 
        // and looks for CustomCursor.MyCursor.Cur in the assemblies manifest. 
    // NOTE: The cursor name is acase sensitive. 
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "MyCursor.cur");  

    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

how about using Cursor property of the form?

```
this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.No;
```